# Freemarker - How to get unprocessed content of custom directive?

Tags: freemarker

I need to create a Freemarker directive that will pass the **unprocessed** content of the tag to a java method. The purpose is to load default template fragments into a DB so they can be examined and edited through another process, then output the result of the edited content if any. I have created a macro that *almost* does this, the problem is that the template fragment is processed before being passed to the java method.

Here is my current code:

```
<#macro process name>
    <#local content><#nested/></#local>
    ${myjava.processContent(name, content)}
</#macro>

<@process 'this-content-name'><p>This is some content about ${companyName}</p></@process>
```

Java:

```
//Add and instance of this class to the Freemarker data model for use in templates.
public class MyJava {

    public String processContent(String name, String content) {
        log.debug("Data To Process: name = {}, content = {}", name, content);

        String contentToOutput = getFromDb(name);
        if(contentToOutput == null) {
            insertContentInDb(name, content);
            contentToOutput = content;
        }
        
        TemplateModel model = Environment.getCurrentEnvironment().getDataModel();
        Configuration config = Environment.getCurrentEnvironment().getConfiguration();
        Template template = new Template("template-from-content", contentToOutput, config);
        return FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(template, model);
    }
}
```

When running the above I need to see the following logged:

```
Data To Process: name = this-content-name, content = <p>This is some content about ${companyName}</p>
```

Unfortunately I see this:

```
Data To Process: name = this-content-name, content = <p>This is some content about My Company Name</p>
```

The problem is clearly that the `<#nested/>` tag is processed by the template engine before it is stored in the local variable in my macro.

Looking into the Freemarker source code I see that `Environment` has `invokeNestedContent()` that appears to handle processing the content of the macro and appears to have methods for retrieving the raw content of the tag, i.e. `<p>This is some content about ${companyName}</p>`. Unfortunately those methods have package-private access and are not accessible from my code.

Is there another way to retrieve the RAW unprocessed content of a custom directive in Freemarker?

It seems like this would be very useful functionality for building content management systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion in @ddekany's answer I was able to come up with two potential solutions which each have some trade offs.

1. Using `TemplateDirectiveModel` and `Environment.getCurrentDirectiveCallPlace()` instead of a macro. The downside of this method is that I am not able to access the containing page's data_model when rendering the `TemplateDirectiveModel`. Additionally, the content retreived includes the full tag, not just its nested content so I have to parse that out.
2. Implementing a freemarker utility class in package `freemarker.core` inside my own source tree. This allows me to access package-private methods, but is obviously not supported by Freemarker.

Option 1 Java:

```
@Slf4j
public class ContentTemplateDirective implements TemplateDirectiveModel {

    private HostData hostDataService;

    public ContentTemplateDirective(HostData hostDataService) {
        this.hostDataService = hostDataService;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Environment environment, Map params, TemplateModel[] loopVars,
                        TemplateDirectiveBody templateDirectiveBody) throws TemplateException, IOException {


        if (!params.containsKey("name")) {
            throw new TemplateModelException(
                    "This directive requires a 'name' parameter.");
        }
        if (loopVars.length != 0) {
            throw new TemplateModelException(
                    "This directive doesn't allow loop variables.");
        }

        String name = params.get("name").toString();
        log.debug("name = {}", name);

        String content = getRawDirectiveContent(true);
        content = hostDataService.removeTag(content, "<@content>");
        log.debug("content = {}", content);

        //This looks for an Element with this name in the DB. If it is not found it creates one with this content.
        //If it is found it overrides this content with the content from the DB.
        content = hostDataService.processElement(name, content, true);


        Configuration config = environment.getConfiguration();
        TemplateModel model = environment.getDataModel();
        Template template = new Template("string-template", content, config);

        StringWriter result = new StringWriter(1024);
        template.process(model, result);
        String output = result.toString();
        
        //Write the output.
        environment.getOut().write(output);
    }

    public static String getRawDirectiveContent(boolean trim) {
        log.debug("Getting Raw Directive Content");
        DirectiveCallPlace dcp = Environment.getCurrentEnvironment().getCurrentDirectiveCallPlace();

        String content =  dcp.getTemplate().getSource(dcp.getBeginColumn(), dcp.getBeginLine(), dcp.getEndColumn(), dcp.getEndLine());
        
        return trim ? content.trim() : content;
    }
}
```

Option 1 FTL:

```
<#assign content = "com.myapp.ContentTemplateDirective"?new(hostDataService)>

<!-- Does not work. Fails to find testValue when evaluating the content. -->
<#assign testValue>Some Test Value</#assign> 
<@content name='page.h2'><h2>This is the default content. Here is a test value: ${testValue}</h2></@content>

<!-- Works, but the testValue has to be assigned inside the <@content> tag so can't access externally assigned model attributes. -->
<@content name='page.h2'>
<#assign testValue>Some Test Value</#assign> 
<h2>This is the default content. Here is a test value: ${testValue}</h2></@content>
```

Option 2 Java (in package freemarker.core):

```
public class MyFreemarkerUtil {

    public static String getRawMacroContent(boolean trim) {
        log.debug("Getting Raw Macro Content");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Environment environment = Environment.getCurrentEnvironment();
        Macro.Context invokingMacroContext = environment.getCurrentMacroContext();
        TemplateObject callPlace = invokingMacroContext.callPlace;
        TemplateElement[] nestedContentBuffer = callPlace instanceof TemplateElement ? ((TemplateElement) callPlace).getChildBuffer() : null;
        if (nestedContentBuffer != null) {
            for (TemplateElement templateElement : nestedContentBuffer) {
                log.debug("templateElement = {}", templateElement);
                sb.append(templateElement.getSource());
            }
        }

        if(trim) {
            return sb.toString().trim();
        } else {
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2 FTL:

```
<#macro content name>
    <#local temlateSource = hostDataService.processContent(name)/>
    <#local inlineTemplate = temlateSource?interpret/>
    <@inlineTemplate/>
</#macro>

<!-- This works. It is able to find the 'testValue' assigned outside the <@content> tag.-->
<#assign testValue>Some Test Value</#assign> 
<@content 'page.h2'><h2>This is the default content. Here is a test value: ${testValue}</h2></@content>
```

After reviewing my options I decided to go with #2 as it worked and should be easy to maintain as long as the Freemarker internal Macro code has package-private access.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather unusual way of using `#nested` for sure. To give some context, `Template` object in theory shouldn't even know how the template source code looked like, as they are primarily to store a kind of a pre-parsed form. But it so happens that `Template`-s actually has a `getSource(col1, row1, col2, row2)` method (which I rather see as a historical artifact, but anyway it's there to stay), so even if it's for tooling (and error messages), the information is there.

So because of the above, the standard way of doing that you do is using `<@process 'foo'><#noparse>...</#noparse></@process>` to prevent processing, although it's a bit too verbose. But, you also want to process (execute) the nested content after capturing it in its raw form, if I see it well (which is odd), which means that you better let FreeMarker parse it together with the rest of the template.

So, I think, you could start out from `Environment.getCurrentDirectiveCallPlace` (please see JavaDoc-s; you probably need to use a `TemplateDirectiveModel` instead of a `#macro`), and that way you have the source code positions, and then use `Template.getSource`. I haven't tried it, but I guess that can work.